# OPENING FILE IN VISUAL STUDIO CODE

Tags: python-3.x, file, path

I am doing a small coding assignment about opening file. However, when I run the code, the program showed this:('Cannot open the file ', 'words.txt', 'please try again'). I tried to search Google to fix the problem but nothing changed. So would anyone mind helping me fix this problem? Thanks in advance.
P/s: This is my code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
try :
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print('Cannot open the file ',fname ,'please try again')
    quit()

for line in fh :
    line = line.upper()
    line = line.rstrip()
    print(line)
```

This is the result when I run the code:

```
Enter file name: 'words.txt'
('Cannot open the file ', 'words.txt', 'please try again')
```

Comment: why don't you use context managers, this not python 2.0

Comment: I think there are 2 general issues. 1.) the `fname` should be a path and name of the file. 2.) there's a second param for this method to indicate the `mode`... do you want to just read the file, write to it, append, etc. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

Comment: make sure you have "words.txt" file on the same folder as your python script.

Comment: One other clarification... you just want to run this python code correct? I think the "visual studio code" isn't really applicable (just the editor you happen to be using) is that correct?